# C# GetConstructor() not returning parent constructors

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor

I'm trying to find a constructor with a specific signature. This constructor does not exist in current type, but it does in its parent. To illustrate:

```
public class Base
{
    public Base()
    {

    }

    public Base(string a1, string a2, string a3)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Child : Base
{

}
```

The problem is, that I can't seem to find the `.ctor` with the string arguments with `.GetConstructor`, even trying such as:

```
typeof(Child).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string) }, null);
```

substituting `typeof(Child)` with `typeof(Base)`, naturally, works.

Is there something I'm missing in respect to finding parent constructors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors are not inherited, so you can't find them through children, even with `FlattenHierarchy`.

You'll have to loop through children to find it.

Answer (score 2):

The Child class simply doesn't have the constructor you are looking for. You cannot write:

```
Child c = new Child("a", "b", "c");
```

So it's meaningless to look for a constructor that cannot be used to instantiate the given type.

All that the Child class has is the default constructor:

```
Child c = new Child();
```

If you remove the default constructor from the `Base` class then the `Child` class will have the constructor you are looking for.

Comment: Removing the default constructor from `Base` does not give `Child` the three parameter constructor.  At first I thought this was something really neat I never knew, but I tried it in .NET 4, and no, still get "'Child' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments"

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
var child = new Child("1", "2", "3")
```

and you'll see why that constructor isn't available on `Child`.